# Angular and sentry/browser causes app to crash

Tags: angular, sentry

I am using Angular: `"@angular/core": "7.2.4",` and sentry: `"@sentry/browser": "4.6.3",`.

With the following code my application correctly throws an error:

```
// import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser';
//
// Sentry.init({
//   dsn: 'mydsn',
//   debug: true
// });

@Injectable()
export class SentryErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor() {}
  handleError(error) {
    throw error;
    // Sentry.captureException(error.originalError || error);
    // throw error;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    // imports
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: SentryErrorHandler},
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

However, as soon as I uncomment sentry, my app just hangs on error, eg:

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser';

Sentry.init({
    dsn: 'mydsn',
    debug: true
});

@Injectable()
export class SentryErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor() {}
  handleError(error) {
    Sentry.captureException(error.originalError || error);
    throw error;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    // imports
  ],
  providers: [
    // {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: SentryErrorHandler},
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I have debug set to true and the console returns:

```
Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: Dedupe
logger.js:30 Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: InboundFilters
logger.js:30 Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: FunctionToString
logger.js:30 Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: ExtraErrorData
logger.js:30 Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: TryCatch
logger.js:30 Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: Breadcrumbs
logger.js:30 Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: GlobalHandlers
logger.js:30 Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: LinkedErrors
logger.js:30 Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: UserAgent
```

In task manager on Google Chrome, CPU spikes and then ultimately the page crashes.

The error I am trying to test with is placing an arbitrary `console.log(t);` Where `t` is an undefined variable.

I am running this from localhost and can confirm I have allowed all traffic in the sentry project settings and can also confirm that the DSN is for the correct account.